# Windows TCP/UDP mouse driver

Tags: c, tcp, udp, driver, wdk

I am working on creating a touch pad device (custom hardware but similar to an android device) that acts as a touchscreen drawing pad similar to the [Wacom Bamboo](http://www.wacom.com/en/products/pen-tablets/bamboo) drawing pads. However, the key feature of the device is instead of connecting it to the computer with wires or via Bluetooth, it connects to the local WiFi network and searches for devices with a port open (currently 5000 for testing purposes). Currently, I have a client written in C that when launched opens up a DatagramSocket on port 5000 and waits for a custom UDP packet containing normalized X, Y, and pressure. Then, for testing purposes, I am putting the normalized X and Y into SendInput. SendInput "works" however injecting packets into the computers current mouse is not what I want. Instead, I want to have it considered as a seperate input device so programs like gimp will be able to detect it and assign custom functions based on the data (ie: have gimp utilize the pressure data).

The problem is I dont know where to start to create a driver that does the former. I have been extensively looking at the winddk thinking that might be the key. The problem with the winddk is I cannot find any documentation on creating a HID driver using data that is not from a ps/2 or usb. [This tutorial](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/06/10/baby-steps-in-windows-device-driver-development-part-3-receiving-ioctls.aspx) got me thinking about using IOCTLs, but I am not really sure how to make them be considered as input.

As a side note, in the title I said TCP/UDP because I am willing, and considering for security purposes, to change from UDP connection to TCP.

If someone can push me in the right direction or link me to some related documentation and samples, that would be awesome because right now I am lost. Thank you.

Comment: http://usbip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Promising, but, correct me if I am wrong, essentially all it does is redirects the USB input to a remote computer picking it up as a USB HID device. Which, even though it is going through ports, it is still a USB input driver.

Comment: Yes, of course. Now you'll have to do something similar vice-a-versa.